# Non expansive function

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space,$F:D \subset X \rightarrow X$ and $\lambda >0$. If $F+\lambda I $ is onto then $R_{\lambda}=(I+\lambda F)^{-1} $ is non expansive, i.e, $|R_{\lambda}(x) -R_{\lambda }(y) | \leq |x-y|. $

I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: @Yanko thanks, i changed it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused in which sense $R_\lambda$ is an inverse. As $F$ is only defined on $D$ so is it an inverse from $X$ to $D$?

Comment: @Yanko Yes, $R_{\lambda}: X \rightarrow D$

Comment: @YAnko, I meant that sorry.

Comment: So if I get it all right. The assumption that $F+\lambda I$ is irrelevant as it is necessarily a bijective (otherwise $R_\lambda$ is not defined).

Comment: You need some additional assumptions on $F$, otherwise it is not true. Consider e.g. $F(x) = -x$ on $X = \mathbb R$ and $\lambda = 1/2$.

Comment: If it can help, $F$ is hyperaccretive, i.e, $F+ \lambda I$ is onto X for all $\lambda >0$.  @gerw

Comment: Is $F $ linear?

Comment: @grew Not necessarily.

Comment: @grew. A new more assumption, F is monotene. I've proven this result in a Hilbert space. I will try it in Banach now.